# How to fix beautiful soup list index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get specific information from the website. It is okey to run first four url, but when we run the fifth one, we get 'IndexError: list index out of range' at 'company = soup.select('.companyName')[0].get_text().strip()'.

we have url like
https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data analyst&l=remote

```
## Number of postings to scrape
postings = 100

jn=0

for i in range(0, postings, 10):
    driver.get(url + "&start=" + str(i))
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    jobs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'job_seen_beacon')

    for job in jobs:
        result_html = job.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result_html, 'html.parser')
        
        jn += 1
        
        liens = job.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
        links = liens[0].get_attribute("href")
        
        title = soup.select('.jobTitle')[0].get_text().strip()
        company = soup.select('.companyName')[0].get_text().strip()
        location = soup.select('.companyLocation')[0].get_text().strip()
        try:
            salary = soup.select('.salary-snippet-container')[0].get_text().strip()
        except:
            salary = 'NaN'
        try:
            rating = soup.select('.ratingNumber')[0].get_text().strip()
        except:
            rating = 'NaN'
        try:
            date = soup.select('.date')[0].get_text().strip()
        except:
            date = 'NaN'
        try:
            description = soup.select('.job-snippet')[0].get_text().strip()
        except:
            description = ''
       
        dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, pd.DataFrame([{'Title': title,
                                          "Company": company,
                                          'Location': location,
                                          'Rating': rating,
                                          'Date': date,
                                          "Salary": salary,
                                          "Description": description,
                                          "Links": links}])], ignore_index=True)
        print("Job number {0:4d} added - {1:s}".format(jn,title))
```

Comment: That would imply that the listing doesn't have a tag with class `companyName`.  Just check for None before you reference `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's safer to check that `select`/`find` returns something before applying `.get...`. When you have to select-and-get from multiple elements, it's more convenient to use a function on loop.

<sub>[This is a simplified version of another function I often use when scraping; if interested, [see an example with the full version](https://pastebin.com/SGQN5pYd).]</sub>

```py
def extractAttr(tag, sel, attr='', defVal=None):
    s = tag.select_one(sel)
    if s is None: return defVal
    if attr == '': 
        stxt = s.get_text(' ').strip()
        return stxt if stxt else defVal
    return s.get(attr, defVal)
```

then you just need to create a reference list with selectors for all the information you need:

```py
selRef = [ # key, selector, attribute, default
    ('Title', '.jobTitle', '', '?'),
    ('Company', '.companyName', '', '?'),
    ('Location', '.companyLocation', '', '?'),
    ('Rating', '.ratingNumber', '', 'NaN'),
    ('Date', '.date', '', 'NaN'),
    ('Salary', '.salary-snippet-container', '', 'NaN'),
    ('Description', '.job-snippet', '', ''),
    ('Links', 'a[href]', 'href', None)
] # be careful to have exactly 4 items in each tuple
```

and you can just simplify your loop to

```py
    for job in jobs:
        result_html = job.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result_html, 'html.parser') 
        jn += 1

        jDict = {k: extractAttr(soup, s, a, d) for k, s, a, d in selRef}
        dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, pd.DataFrame([jDict])])
        print("Job number {0:4d} added - {1:s}".format(jn, jDict['Title']))
```